# What law designated the U.S. Marshals as non-military?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, military

What is the code that says that the United States of America Marshals will not be seen as the military anymore?

Answer (score 8):

The US Marshals (now the US Marshals Service) was -- as described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Marshals_Service) -- created by the [Judiciary Act of 1789](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_Act_of_1789) during the first term of the US Congress (and also during the first term of office of George Washington as President of the United States). See also [this page](https://www.usmarshals.gov/history/broad_range.htm) from the US Marshals Service web site.

The Marshals have never been part of the military, and they claim to be the oldest national law enforcement organization in the US. They are not and never have been part of the US Army or Navy. According to the Wikipedia article linked above:

> The Marshals Service is the primary agency for fugitive operations, the protection of officers of the Federal Judiciary, the management of criminal assets, the operation of the United States Federal Witness Protection Program and the Justice Prisoner and Alien Transportation System, and execution of federal arrest warrants. Throughout its history, the Marshals have also provided unique security and enforcement services including protecting African-American students enrolling in the South during the civil rights movement, escort security for United States Air Force LGM-30 Minuteman missile convoys, law enforcement for the United States Antarctic Program, and protection of the Strategic National Stockpile.

The United States Marshals Service, a federal agency, was created in 1969.

Comment: Very well @Burt_Harris,  I have changed my answer to say that they **claim** to be the oldest, which the surely do, and the linked Wikipedia article accepts that claim. The poit reelvant to this answer is merely that they are almost as old as the country itself, and have always been law enforcement, not military.

Comment: I agree that's really the important point.

Comment: Post civil war the U.S. Marcheals where implemented into the country the United States of America as the millatay then the countery faced the problem of what to do in ploicing.

Comment: The answer has just said they **have never been** part of the military. If you dispute the answer when you had to ask the question in the first place, please provide your own answer supported by references, or accept that your original conception was incorrect. @JasonNaillieux

Comment: That is crazy. I asked the quest and gave the history I know for the refece to who may answer the quest not for who may dispute the facts of the questions.

Comment: @JasonNaillieux The problem is that the premise of the question is wrong in a way that makes the question impossible to answer without correcting the premise. The US Marshals were *never* the military. There is no law saying the Marshals will no longer be the military, because that would require the Marshals to have been the military at some point.

Comment: @Jason Naillieux, try reading the linked sources, one of which is from the Marshals Service itself. I don't know why you think that the Marshals were once part of the military, but that is incorrect. And it isn't your question page, it is StackExchange's site

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I seem to recall watching a couple of old Western movies many years ago where the local sheriff / marshal would call upon the US Cavalry to bolster his posse to track and catch the bad guys. Maybe this is the source of confusion?

Comment: @Rock As often Hollywood gets it wrong. That would have violated the [*Posse Comitatus Act*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posse_Comitatus_Act) of 1878, actually passed to end the Reconstruction military occupation of the South. Pre-hollywood, it was a cliche of bad melodrama (plays) that the villain would be vanquished by the US Cavalry, coming on scene (a version of *Deus ex machina*). I have no idea where this came from, but in any case the Marshals never were the Cavalry.

Comment: @Rock Perhaps the mistake is because the [Earl Marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Marshal) was, back in the days of Henry III, the commander of the English military.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Many U.S. Westerns are set prior to 1878. The act was, in part, designed to end the practice depicted in those movies.